# How to manage async functions using React Hooks API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am working with React Hooks and i am trying to update state then do something async and then do someting based on state. This doesn't work since the update state is not available inside the async function. How could you solve such a task using react hooks?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-async-actions-using-state-7cuit)

I basically tried to change the scope of the function but apparently its all immuteable which means the refrences inside the async functions points to old state.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

// Constants
function somethingAsync(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const doSomethingAsync = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await somethingAsync(2000);
    if (loading) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>Current Status: {loading ? "Loading" : "Not Loading"}</p>
      <button onClick={doSomethingAsync}>Do Something Async</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I would like the loading flag to be reset back to false everytime the async function is done and this should be done based on state the have been updated while doing the async function. Right now it only works every second time due to the old references in the async scope.

Comment: I didn't look closely in your code, but I would use `useEffect` hook if I want to execute something based on state changes

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the if around your `setLoading(false)` call.

If you don't, that function will access a stale `loading` status. Because when that function was created, `loading` was false. So, after you run your async function, after the await, your function will resume, and even though `loading` is `true` it will see it as false. But you'll know that it will be `true` because you just set it and your `App` has re-rendered at the `await` statement. See the behavior below:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-async-actions-using-state-60ynv)

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

// Constants
function somethingAsync(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  console.log("App rendering...");

  const doSomethingAsync = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log("Before await...");
    await somethingAsync(2000);
    console.log("After await...");
    setLoading(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>Current Status: {loading ? "Loading" : "Not Loading"}</p>
      <button onClick={doSomethingAsync}>Do Something Async</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Alright, but i my case what if i need the updated state :-) ? 

Let's say that something is updated and i need the updated value in my async function. Is there any way to achive this :-) ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `if` condition in your async function:

```
  const doSomethingAsync = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      await somethingAsync(2000);
      setLoading(false);      
    };
```

Comment: Alright, but i my case what if i need the updated state :-) ? Let's say that something is updated and i need the updated value in my async function. Is there any way to achive this :-) ?

Comment: You need to look into `useEffect` for that: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html